# Add attribute to Child element in Grape Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, grapesjs

I'm working in [grape js](https://grapesjs.com/docs/) for the long time .

Now I face some issue init.

**Issue:**

This is the component I try to add in Editor.

```
<div class="page">
      <div class="col1"></div>
      <div class="col2"></div>
 </div>
```

After adding those components I try to add some computed values to the elements like this,

```
element.on('component:add',function(ele){
   ele.addAttributes({
     'data-top' : topOffset,
     'data-left' : leftOffset,
   });

   editor.render();// For render Updated html
});
```

But, this code only update the `.page` component only.

How Can I add those attr into `.col1,.col2` elements inside `.page` component ?

Comment: can you console.log(ele) ? Please share the output on console with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation and there does not seem to be a straightforward way to get what you want. However you can do something like below snippet. It iterates over all child elements and adds the attributes to them.

```
editor.on('component:add', function (ele, argument) {
   ele.setAttributes({
     'data-top' : 10,
     'data-left' : 20,
   });

   ele.attributes.components.models.forEach(function(item){
      if(item.attributes.tagName == 'div') {
         item.setAttributes({
           'data-top' : 10,
           'data-left' : 20,
         })
      }
   })

   editor.render();// For render Updated html
})
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the Help

Comment: Glad to be of help!